# display: none is not working in ie alone it works in ff and chrome

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

hey dudes recently i came across a bizzare problem while trying to learn tabbing .. my code worked like charm in firefox and chrome it didn't work in any version of ie ...There will be two tabs and related contents when i click on tab1 corresponding content should be shown hiding other one ..same goes for tab2 it worked in ff and chrome .. but ie add all contents as i switch to other tabs my code goes like this http://jsfiddle.net/myth/PZZ6a/16/

Comment: It works in jsfiddle (in Chrome, anyway) if instead of "onLoad" you set that fiddle control to "no wrap (body)".

Comment: Do you have a small, reproducible test case?

Comment: it doesn't work in ie dude that's my problem..it does work in ff and chrome

Comment: @pal nope dude .. this one itself very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to "getElementsByName" aren't working for you. I *think* that's because "name" is not a proper attribute for `<a>` elements, but I have not found any MSDN documentation supporting that notion.  The behavior, however, very strongly suggests that that's the case.

*edit* — well no, it doesn't seem that "name" is improper for `<a>` elements after all; however, for whatever reason that's the cause of your problems. The calls to "getElementsByName" are returning empty node lists, so your "for" loops don't do anything.

Comment: help me to get rid of the prob dude!!

Comment: I agree that it appears to be an IE issue. You could use getElementsByTagName and then search for the ones you want.  This is the sort of thing that client-side frameworks make **much** easier.

Comment: thanks dude for pointing out the prob btw how u find that getelementsbyname is not working in IE alone pls explain ,i have found working solution too thanks ton mate ..

Comment: I just played with your jsfiddle example and checked with the debugger (in IE8).

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has to do with `getElementsByName` not working with the `div` element in IE. Easy fix though since you already have classes on those two things, use `getElementsByClassName`.

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
var seltabs= document.getElementsByClassName("seltab");
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CeVa9/1/

Note: Tested in IE9.